# on() to watch changes in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

How can I compare the new value inserted by the user and the current value that already existed in the input?

Comment: You'll need to save the original value in a variable. The DOM doesn't have that information AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly, the input's `value` attribute is not actually updated when its value is changed. Therefore you can simply compare the `.val()` to the `attr("value")` and update the `attr("value")` after a change is made:

E.G:

```js
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).attr("value")+" vs "+$(this).val());
   $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextBox" value="abc" />
```

Comment: how about `select` element?

Comment: @Jennifer if you asking if this will work with `select` boxes then no, selects don't have a value attribute. You'll need something a little more robust such as https://jsfiddle.net/jntc3jfv/

Answer (score 3):

This is where you can use a closure:

```js
  $("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", (function() {
    var previousValue = $("#myTextBox").val();
    return function() {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        alert('Was ' + previousValue + " and now it's " + newValue);
        previousValue = newValue;
    };
})());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextBox" value="abc" />
```

The reason for the slightly convoluted closure: it creates a variable called `previousValue` that has a lifetime greater than the handler function, but yet can only be accessed by this handler function. You are guaranteed not to have naming collisions with other parts of your code.

Comment: good solution!! I've thinking about retrieve the previous value on TextBox's clickEvent, but your solution is more clean and easy to understand.

Comment: Hmm why u need a function in this case? and it's a return function? I don't get this in the function part, does the function execute later? if yes what's the return for?

Comment: @Jennifer - The outer function is called onetime, straight away. It generates a new function that acts as the handler. This handler function is called on each change, and has access to the `previousValue` variable.
Here's a page about javascript closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 2):

You can save the previous value on the element itself and get it when the value changes.

```js
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  // Get previous and current value
  var prevValue = $(this).data('value'),
    currValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(prevValue + ' === ' + currValue);

  // Update the prevValue
  $(this).data('value', currValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can Save any value in JavaScript you can Save or Keep the previous data in 3 common ways:

1. Make a Variable and set to the value before it changes
2. Push to an Array
3. Add it to an Object as a Value
   etc.

The best way you do it is using Variable, so something like this:
  var previousValue = $ (this).val ();

and access it after...

```
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", function () {
    var preValue = $(this).val();
    return function () {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        consol.log('preValue: ' + preValue + 'newValue: ' + newValue);
        preValue = newValue;
    };
});
```

The return happens after, so it works likes a Callback, basically it happens after and this way you can save both Variables...

Comment: 4. Use Markdown efficiently and correctly. Hope it's helping.

Comment: Thanks mate, yes, for some reasons my SOF didn't accept my CRTL+K :)